# Simple bug crashes hangs Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have build the simplest possible iPhone program, a window based program. I only changed the testappdelegate.h file to be the following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    int pos[10]10]; //note the error here.
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Note the error in the 'int pos...' line.

When I try to compile this program XCode hangs (showing millions of errors). I am not asking how to fix the line, the fix is obvious.

The problem is that overwhelms XCode and I want to know why?

Update: submitted bug report Bug ID# 8406197

**Update2: Sept 24.** I got a response from Apple
Engineering has provided the following information:

We don't plan to fix this in llvm-gcc or gcc, and it is already fixed in clang.  Xcode not freaking out is tracked in a clone of this bug.

We are now closing this bug since our engineers are aware of the issue and will continue to track it offline.

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug at bugreporter.apple.com and posing the same question. This has more to do with Xcode's behavior than software development.

Comment: This is not an interesting question at all. You're seriously asking the community to explain the "why" behind a performance bug in a closed source program?

Comment: It is a very interesting problem and highly relevant.   As well, it is an issue that others might run into and, with this question, folks may easily find this particular Stack Overflow question to help guide them.

Comment: @bbum there's no guarantee this behaviour won't disappear in the next version of Xcode, or isn't localized to a specific version of Xcode, or even a specific install of the OP's -- minutiae for a blog, maybe, but not a "real" question for SO.

Comment: There is also no guarantee that such behavior isn't universal to a particular pathological situation, doesn't affect many developers, isn't localized to newbies, and isn't somehow otherwise pervasive across some significant subset of the community.  There might also be a workaround that those "in the know" can provide.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't think the hostility from blucz was necessary. I am of the opinion, however, that SO probably isn't the best place for IDE bug discussion. Obviously the community is divided over that particular opinion. :-)

Comment: Well... given that the vast majority of iPhone developers use Xcode to do their development and Xcode + IB very much is the "user interface" to the underlying language and APIs, I would consider strongly that the IDE is very much an intrinsic part of the platform experience.

Comment: @Joshua it's not clear that it's just an IDE bug. GCC is an accomplice in this, as it keeps trying to compile the file. Unfortunately I have not the ability nor the time to try figure out what gcc is thinking. It was hard enough tracking this bug bug.

Comment: @Shaggy Frog: I guarantee it wouldn't get fixed if the Xcode developers don't know it exists.  And they might not know it exists if John Smith had not reported it and John Smith might not have reported it if bbum hadn't told him to do so on Stack OVerflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that Xcode is having to ingest those millions of errors to try and figure out if there is a line of code that needs annotation.

Please file a bug via http://bugreport.apple.com/.

That you have produced such a simple test case will help the engineering team to ensure that any fixes they may be pursuing address the problem sufficiently.   There are potentially two bugs here; the first for Xcode to handle such a volume of errors gracefully and the second for the compiler to not spew so much in the face of such an obvious error.

It is likely that your bug(s) will be returned as known duplicates.  That only happens, though, after the engineering team has captured any unique information from your bug.   That is to say, dupes are often very useful.

When filing the bug, add the bug # to your SO question.   Many Apple engineers cruise SO and will click through to followup internally.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll add some notes.

Answer (score 1):

Some errors, the compiler doesn't know what to do next.

The fact that the syntax error appears to be one local to a single line to you, a human, doesn't mean necessarily mean that there was a simple rule that was obvious to the compiler writer.